# Chromium CSS Link from CDN ignored

Tags: html, css, chromium

I'm having a sudden problem when loading my site. http://busme.us. with a newer version of Chromium.

It appears that my one of my stylesheets is not being applied to the elements as I can figure out from Inspect Element.

The link in question is the following:

`<link href="http://objects.dreamhost.com/busme-prod-files/main/538e298e22f324388b007ab8/original/style.css" rel="stylesheet">`

However, the main CSS seems to be processed and is assigning CSS to elements, which is:

`<link href="//busme-prod-assets.objects.dreamhost.com/assets/normal-layout-3df2197619a7f407056e8569a5b5819f.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

It all works on Firefox and Safari. It does NOT work on the following versions of Chromium.

Version 45.0.2454.85 Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit)
Version 44.0.2403.89 Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit)

These were upgraded from previous Chromium browsers that did work.
So, something changed in the upgrade of Chromium? I don't have older versions to test anymore since I upgraded.

If I download the contents of `style.css` and using Developer Tools I insert a `<style>` element containing the contents of `style.css`, it works. So, I believe it is not a syntax issue particular to Chrome.

Furthermore, I have seen other answers, such as the CDN is returning the wrong content type of `binary/octet-stream`, but this content type is the same for both of the CSS files in question, so why does one work and not the other? Anyway, I cannot really change the response type since I don't control the CDN.

Before you start pointing out the `type="text/css"` and `media="all"` and `http:` differences in the links, I've changed those as well. Inspect Element says it has downloaded the `style.css` file and it states that its "Type" is 'stylesheet', same for `normal-layout.css`

I've even made changes to make the links look exactly the same by downloading the page into a file, editing it locally, and loading it from the file with the same results.  Try it!

So, I'm really at a loss of what is going on.

Why is it only Chrome? What is the incompatibility with other browsers?

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is most likely the incorrect Content Type. Talk to dreamhost, you have to be able to set the Content Type, otherwise the CDN isn't usable at all.

Comment: @EmilStenström, Then I don't really understand why the `normal-layout.css` works, because all indications from InspectElement is that it comes from the same place and with the same content type.

Comment: As the answer states below using `curl -I`, `normal-layout.css` did have a response header of `Content-type: text/css`, while `style.css` had a response header of `undefined` for Content-type. However, I have no idea why the Developer Tools of Chrome in the Network tab said `binary/octet-stream` for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment above, the problem is actually the `Content-type` header.

Specifically, the http://objects.dreamhost.com/busme-prod-files/main/538e298e22f324388b007ab8/original/style.css file is being served with a `Content-type: undefined` header. It should be `Content-type: text/css`.

The other file you mention, http://busme-prod-assets.objects.dreamhost.com/assets/normal-layout-3df2197619a7f407056e8569a5b5819f.css, is served with `Content-type: text/css`, and that’s why it works as expected.

---

#### Verifying Content-type on your own

To verify headers yourself, you can use the `curl` command with the `-I` option, like this:

```
curl -I http://objects.dreamhost.com/busme-prod-files/main/538e298e22f324388b007ab8/original/style.css
```

That produces this output:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 16795
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Last-Modified: Tue, 03 Jun 2014 20:01:18 GMT
ETag: "06b3748eba4f2e5ccb70e8444abd5c77"
Content-type: undefined
Date: Thu, 24 Sep 2015 21:33:18 GMT
```

Compare that to running this:

```
curl -I http://busme-prod-assets.objects.dreamhost.com/assets/normal-layout-3df2197619a7f407056e8569a5b5819f.css
```

That produces this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 239447
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Last-Modified: Thu, 07 May 2015 05:44:24 GMT
ETag: "e4b17d7e6405120b1488079bb0081e6f"
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31557600
Expires: Fri, 06 May 2016 11:44:23 GMT
Content-type: text/css
Date: Thu, 24 Sep 2015 21:33:36 GMT
```

If you don’t have the `curl` command installed but do have the `wget` command, you can get similar information with `wget -S`, like this:

```
wget -S http://objects.dreamhost.com/busme-prod-files/main/538e298e22f324388b007ab8/original/style.css
```

---

> Furthermore, I have seen other answers, such as the CDN is returning
>   the wrong content type of binary/octet-stream, but this content type
>   is the same for both of the CSS files in question, so why does one
>   work and not the other?

As the `curl -I` output above indicates, the `Content-type` for the files you mention is not actually the same; one has the correct `Content-type: text/css` header, while the other doesn't.

If you’re able to serve the file from `http://busme-prod-assets.objects.dreamhost.com` with the correct `Content-type: text/css` header, then you should you be able to ensure that the curl -I `http://objects.dreamhost.com/busme-prod-files` files also get the right `Content-type`.

Comment: That was exactly my idea to do this test morning this morning. Now I wonder why Chromium Developer Tools reports both in the Network tab as being `binary/octet-stream`. And my next problem is how do I tell Dreamhost, which I am not fond of and will probably drop, how to do this specific content type designation.

Comment: Yeah when I can make some time, I will try to investigate what changed around this in Chromium recently. As far as Dreamhost, if you could move to self-hosting at Digital Ocean or somewhere you definitely gain a lot more flexibility (but at the cost of needing to do more of system maintenance on your own.)

Comment: Just as a note for others. I re-uploaded the files to Dreamhost using a Ubuntu available python tool called `s3cmd`, but I had to modify it to use Dreamhost instead of Amazon. My CMS uploaded the files without the proper mimetype (something else I surmise I have to fix). I individually changed all of my `.css` files to `text/css` and `.js` files to `text/javascript`. Now things are working on Chrome. It was a pain, but at least this stuff doesn't change much. Talk about some do good developer in an office or his basement thinking he's doing a "good thing," while breaking the world!